# SQL and ASP.NET The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Int64' type to the 'System.Int32' type is not valid

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I am using ASP.NET entity framework and I am trying to create an SqlQuery but I get this error:

> The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Int64' type to the
>   'System.Int32' type is not valid.

My problem is I don't know which column is giving me trouble and how to fix it. Here is my code. I don't think its my casts that I am doing because those are strings.

```
return View(db.Data.SqlQuery("SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY slotOrder ASC) AS id, 
                              concat(a.dateSlot, ' - ', a.timeSlot) as dateSlot, 
                              concat(a.dateSlot, '-', a.timeSlot) as timeSlot, 
                              COUNT(*) as slotOrder 
                              FROM Appointments a 
                              LEFT OUTER JOIN dateTimeSlots b 
                              ON a.dateSlot = b.dateSlot AND a.timeSlot = b.timeSlot 
                              GROUP BY a.dateSlot, a.timeSlot, b.slotOrder 
                              ORDER BY b.slotOrder").ToList());
```

Here is my class:

```
public class dateTimeSlots
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Date")]
    public string dateSlot { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Time")]
    public string timeSlot { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Order")]
    public int slotOrder { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is the model class yo are storing it into? Please add it too. Either `id` or `slotOrder` are longs and not ints. Probably `id`

Comment: Added Class to my question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your query above returns an `Int64` (`long`) and you are storing it as an `Int32` (`int`). Find out which of the numeric fields it is and adjust model.

My guess is that the `id` is `long` as it is `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Answer (score 2):

`ROW_NUMBER()` returns a `bigint` ([MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql)), which translates as `Int64` or `long` in C#.